# Koin não consegue injetar as minhas classes no android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, injeção-de-dependência

Eu configurei a injeção de dependências do meu projeto e estou recebendo um erro que não entendi muito bem e não achei em nenhum outro lugar.

Tenho dois arquivos AppModule.kt em módulos diferentes.

Este é o primeiro:

```
val viewModelModule = module {
    viewModel { HomeViewModel(useCase = get()) }
}
```

Esse é o outro:

```
val apiServiceModule = module {
 single<Retrofit> {
  Retrofit.Builder()
   .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
   .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
   .build()
 }

 single<ApiService> {
  get<Retrofit>().create(ApiService::class.java)
 }
}

val repositoryModule = module {
 factory<GalleryRepository> {
  GalleryRepositoryImpl(apiService = get())
 } bind GalleryRepository::class
}

val useCaseModule = module {
 factory<GalleryUseCase> {
  GalleryUseCaseImpl(repository = get())
 } bind GalleryUseCase::class
}
```

Estou recebendo este erro:

```
2021-12-01 18:58:05.634 29675-29675/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.luishenrique.cutecatsgallery, PID: 29675
    java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:944)
        at org.koin.ext.KClassExtKt.getFullName(KClassExt.kt:25)
        at org.koin.core.definition.BeanDefinitionKt.indexKey(BeanDefinition.kt:89)
        at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveDefinition$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:100)
        at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:110)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveValue(Scope.kt:254)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:241)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:204)
        at com.luishenrique.domain.di.AppModuleKt$useCaseModule$1$1.invoke(AppModule.kt:43)
        at com.luishenrique.domain.di.AppModuleKt$useCaseModule$1$1.invoke(AppModule.kt:35)
        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:53)
        at org.koin.core.instance.FactoryInstanceFactory.get(FactoryInstanceFactory.kt:38)
        at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:110)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveValue(Scope.kt:254)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:241)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:204)
        at com.luishenrique.domain.di.AppModuleKt$useCaseModule$1$1.invoke(AppModule.kt:43)
        at com.luishenrique.domain.di.AppModuleKt$useCaseModule$1$1.invoke(AppModule.kt:35)
        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:53)
        at org.koin.core.instance.FactoryInstanceFactory.get(FactoryInstanceFactory.kt:38)
        at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:110)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveValue(Scope.kt:254)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:241)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:204)
        at com.luishenrique.domain.di.AppModuleKt$useCaseModule$1$1.invoke(AppModule.kt:43)
        at com.luishenrique.domain.di.AppModuleKt$useCaseModule$1$1.invoke(AppModule.kt:35)
        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:53)
        at org.koin.core.instance.FactoryInstanceFactory.get(FactoryInstanceFactory.kt:38)
        at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:110)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveValue(Scope.kt:254)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:241)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:204)
        at com.luishenrique.domain.di.AppModuleKt$useCaseModule$1$1.invoke(AppModule.kt:43)
        at com.luishenrique.domain.di.AppModuleKt$useCaseModule$1$1.invoke(AppModule.kt:35)
        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:53)
        at org.koin.core.instance.FactoryInstanceFactory.get(FactoryInstanceFactory.kt:38)
        at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:110)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveValue(Scope.kt:254)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:241)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:204)
        at com.luishenrique.domain.di.AppModuleKt$useCaseModule$1$1.invoke(AppModule.kt:43)
        at com.luishenrique.domain.di.AppModuleKt$useCaseModule$1$1.invoke(AppModule.kt:35)
        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:53)
        at org.koin.core.instance.FactoryInstanceFactory.get(FactoryInstanceFactory.kt:38)
        at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:110)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveValue(Scope.kt:254)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:241)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:204)
        at com.luishenrique.domain.di.AppModuleKt$useCaseModule$1$1.invoke(AppModule.kt:43)
        at com.luishenrique.domain.di.AppModuleKt$useCaseModule$1$1.invoke(AppModule.kt:35)
        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:53)
        at org.koin.core.instance.FactoryInstanceFactory.get(FactoryInstanceFactory.kt:38)
2021-12-01 18:58:07.283 29675-29675/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:53)
        at org.koin.core.instance.FactoryInstanceFactory.get(FactoryInstanceFactory.kt:38)
        at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:110)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveValue(Scope.kt:254)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:241)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:204)
        at com.luishenrique.cutecatsgallery.di.AppModuleKt$viewModelModule$1$1.invoke(AppModule.kt:14)
        at com.luishenrique.cutecatsgallery.di.AppModuleKt$viewModelModule$1$1.invoke(AppModule.kt:8)
        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:53)
        at org.koin.core.instance.FactoryInstanceFactory.get(FactoryInstanceFactory.kt:38)
        at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:110)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveValue(Scope.kt:254)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:241)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:204)
        at androidx.lifecycle.StateViewModelFactory.create(StateViewModelFactory.kt:17)
        at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:69)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
        at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.ViewModelResolverKt.resolveInstance(ViewModelResolver.kt:15)
        at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.scope.ScopeExtKt.getViewModel(ScopeExt.kt:67)
        at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.scope.ScopeExtKt.getViewModel(ScopeExt.kt:53)
        at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.scope.ScopeExtKt.getViewModel$default(ScopeExt.kt:45)
        at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.ext.android.ComponentCallbackExtKt.getViewModel(ComponentCallbackExt.kt:63)
        at com.luishenrique.cutecatsgallery.ui.view.HomeActivity$special$$inlined$viewModel$default$2.invoke(ComponentCallbackExt.kt:65)
        at com.luishenrique.cutecatsgallery.ui.view.HomeActivity$special$$inlined$viewModel$default$2.invoke(ComponentCallbackExt.kt:42)
        at kotlin.UnsafeLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:81)
        at com.luishenrique.cutecatsgallery.ui.view.HomeActivity.getMViewModel(HomeActivity.kt:15)
        at com.luishenrique.cutecatsgallery.ui.view.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.kt:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2742)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2872)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1595)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6543)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri que o erro era porque que eu estava injetando uma classe dentro dela mesma.
Mudei isso:

```
class GalleryUseCaseImpl(private val repository: GalleryUseCase): GalleryUseCase {
```

Para isso:

```
class GalleryUseCaseImpl(private val repository: GalleryRepository): GalleryUseCase {
```